# Geocoding передача в URL точного адреса

Tags: google-maps, jquery, google-maps-api, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Нужно передать в url точный адрес, например, Минск Шаранговича 15 к.3.
Передаётся только город, улица и номер дома, а вот корпус не могу. Подскажите, как это сделать!

url:

```
'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Минск+Шаранговича+15+1&sensor=false&language=ru'
```

Получаю результат Шаранговича 1. :(

Comment: к сожалению, не всегда получается определить, например есть адрес Минск Асаналиева 13 к1, к2, к3. К3 находит, а вот остальные нет. Но всё равно оформляйте ответ, я его приму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по редиректу Гугл не знает [такого адреса](https://www.google.ru/maps/place/%D1%83%D0%BB.+%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0+15%2F3,+%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA,+%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C/), и перекидывает на 49/3, а вообще нужно писать вот так, чтобы найти адрес с корпусом через дробь: address=Минск+Шаранговича+15%2F3

**UPD** Обновил ссылку, похоже она не проходила ограничение.

По поводу улицы Асаналиева, то гугл как раз определяет [дом 13](https://www.google.ru/maps/place/пер.+Асаналиева+13,+Минск,+Беларусь) и [дом 13 корпус 3](https://www.google.com/maps/place/ул.+Асаналиева+13\3,+Минск,+Беларусь/)

В любом случае, перед поиском адреса через API можно поискать его на карте гугла, если найдёт на карте - значит он есть и в API карт, база ведь одна